# Having an attribute issue with my django project. I'm doing an ecommerce website with this code

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to fix this issue with my project and this error shows up and I can't seem to fix it. Is there a way to fix it? its saying that cannot import name 'Product' from 'store.models'
[[image: Error 1][image: error2]

Comment: It may happen because "Product" is a sub class of Category

Comment: how can I fix this?

Comment: let "Class Product" start from the beginning of the line and also edit it's content and also your __str__ function

Answer (score 0):

Is it because of indentation?  Your class "Product" is nested inside of your class "Category"  try fixing the indentations.  If that doesn't work, please provide the error message that you're getting.

Comment: How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Highlight the entire class "Product" in your code editor and then press shift+tab at the same time until the product class is aligned with the category class.